# get PDO search result in an array

Tags: php, pdo

I have a PDO query to select diary from the past five years of the same date :

```
$sql = 'select * from diary where dtime in (?,?,?,?,?) order by dtime desc';
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute($fiveYears); //pass in the $fiveYear array of five dates like 2014-03-01, 2013-03-01 ~ 2010-03-01
```

and then I echo out the result using a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($result as $row){
~~echo table contents here~~
}
```

I want to display the content in five tables, even if there is no content for that year, but the foreach loop only echos out the dates that have content.  So if there is content for 2014-03-01 and 2012-03-01, the result is:

- 2014-03-01: diary contents
- 2012-03-01: diary contents

But I want it to show

- 2014-03-01: diary contents
- 2013-03-01: empty
- 2012-03-01: diary contents
- 2011-03-01: empty
- 2010-03-01: empty

Can you please help me on how I can achieve this?
Should I combine the $fiveYear array with the result array?  How?
Should I use the in_array in PHP?
Or is there a better way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as this simple task require a bit more understanding than local folks has (and even require reading of the question body!)

```
$date_start = '2012-03-01';
$date_end   = '2012-03-31';
$range      = array();
$date       = $date_start;
while ($date <=  $date_end)
{
    $range[] = $date;
    $date    = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$date + 1 day"));
}

$sql = 'select * from diary where dtime BETWEEN ? AND ? order by dtime desc';
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($date_start, $date_end));
$result = array();
while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
    $result[$row['dtime']] = $row;
}
?>
<?php foreach ($range as $day): ?>
<?=$day?>:
<?php if (isset($result[$day])): ?>
diary entry <?=$result[$day]['title']?>
<? else: ?>
empty
<? endif ?>
```

However, if dtime contains datetime value, as name suggests, it won't work. you need to select `DATE(dtime) as dtime, *` in your query then

Comment: thanks for the comments :) read the question about 4 times but still misunderstood it, until I read your code